# single logger in python project?

Tags: python, logging

I'd like to create a logger for a python project. I want to make sure that i'm using the same logger for every module in the project. What is the best way to do this? It seems I need a global logging object? Or perhaps a logging module that is imported by every other module? I want to make sure that I'm always writing to the same log file.

I'm using python's logger and handler already. The problem is that I have to define which file the logger will write to in every module. I'd like to define the log file path once and have it be used for every module.

Comment: `logging` does this for you.  It's built-in.  Read about it here: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Comment: Have you considered using syslog? http://docs.python.org/library/syslog.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, look at Python's [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html)

It provides objects like Logger and Handler, I think it can work for you.

Comment: i'm using the logger and handler now. The problem is that I have to define which file to write to at the top of every module.

Comment: @Ramy: That's false.  The "main" module can configure logging, the one that runs the application as a whole.  All other modules can simply get a logger.

Comment: I must be missing something. If I import logger and define the file the logger would write to in one module, how do I reference that object in a different module?

Comment: @Ramy: Modules are singletons, just do the `logging.basicConfig( .. )` setup once and use it everywhere, without reconfiguring it.

Comment: ah, i see. What I was missing is that you have to call the logging.getLogger method at the top of each module. not redefine the filename. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: You don't even have to call getLogger (except once, in your main.py, to configure it.) Everywhere else, you can just import logging and then call logging.info(...) or whatever.

Answer (score 3):

The [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is ideal for situations like this.  In Python, you'd implement it something like this:

```
class MySingleton(object):
     __instance = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.__instance:
            raise Exception, """
                             Tried to allocate a second instance of a singleton.
                             Use getInstance() instead.
                             """

        self.__class__.__instance = self

    @classmethod
    def getInstance(cls):
        if not cls.__instance:
            cls()

        return cls.__instance
```

Then you can import the module as you normally would and use MySingleton.getInstance() to get an instance of the class.  Within a given application, you're guaranteed that you'll always get the same instance.

EDIT: Others have pointed out the [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module, and I'd agree with them that using that is probably a better option than writing your own logger.  However, if you do need to write your own logger for whatever reason, the above pattern is probably what you'll want to use.

Comment: I like this Singleton solution. Its nice and simple. But it didn't work. I made 2 instances and both run. This is what i tried: http://pastebin.com/zq8J7dCn

Comment: Oops - I coded that off the top of  my head and didn't test it, so it has a bit of a bug with how the __instance class variable was set.  I've fixed that, so if you update your code to match my new code it should work (I tested it this time.)  As others have mentioned though, if you just need logging, you're probably better off with the logging class: http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html

Answer (score 1):

Define the logger object in the __builtin__ module. That way, you can access it like any other python global function, without importing some logging module in every file.

in logmodule.py:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.log = logging.getLogger('global')
# ... configure your logger
```

In your 'main' file:

```
import logmodule
```

In some other file:

```
log.debug('blah')
```

Answer (score -1):

### **use negar module ...**

[github negar module](https://github.com/sys113/negar)

> **install negar ...**

```
python3 -m pip install negar
```

> **code**

```
from negar import log

# method one

def x():
    text = 'hello world!'
    return text

log('\'x\' function return value is '+'\''+str(x())+'\'')

# method two

def y():
    text = 'hello world!'
    return text

log(text = '\'y\' function return value is '+'\''+str(x())+'\'' , save = 'function-log.txt' , size = 1)
```

> **result**

[image: result]